# Why does the cookie expire?

Tags: php, cookies

On my website I set some cookies when users login so I can remember them so they don't have to login every time they re-visit the website.

I set the cookies in php using the following code:

```
setcookie("last_login", $loginID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

And in my php.ini I even got this setting:

session.cookie_lifetime = 2592000

But even with all this when i close down the browser and re-open the website the cookies don't work in my php code and they dose not get logged in, but even more weird. Then when i try yo echo the cookie using:

```
echo $_COOKIE["last_login"];
```

It in the begining does not show up but sometimes after a few reloads it just randomly starts working with the cookie and it echo it out and you get logged in...?

So how can i make it so the cookies allways work within the next 30 days without it being weird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes browsers clear cookies when closing them. A few things you can check just to be sure:

- Is this happening in just one browser or all browsers you can get your hands on?
- Is the time on your system correct?
- Does `setcookie` return `TRUE`? Check it: `var_dump(setcookie("last_login", $loginID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"));`
- Is the correct php.ini loaded? Check `phpinfo()` to see if the settings you changed are visible or not.

## Edit:

Responding to the follow up question about the domain (see comment): Yes you can.

```
setcookie("last_login", $loginID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", "domain.com");
```

Comment: I know its beeing set because in the begining when i enter the website they dont work. But when i edit in my file to echo the cookie it sometimes start working again after not been working and i have not been setting them again when that happens...?

Comment: If you haven't already, try my suggestions to be more certain of your situation.

Comment: Never mind, it was because i sometimes used www.domain.com and sometimes domain.com, is there i way i can set the cookie for both while on www.domain.com?